# Will a snapshot contain an error when throwing an exception?

Tags: flutter, dart

This method sends a message and returns `Future<bool>`. I case when status in not 200 will the snapshot contains error or it will crash the whole app by throwing an exception?

```
Future<bool> sendMessage(String id, String message) async {
  /* sendind logic */
  if (r.statusCode == 200) {
    return true;
  } else {
    print('Failed to send message. Status code: ${r.statusCode}');
    throw Exception('Failed to send message. Status code: ${r.statusCode}');
  }
}
```

and proceed it this way

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: result,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Center(child: Text('Success'));
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Center(child: Text("${snapshot.error}"));
      }
      return kLoading;
    },
  ),
```

In case when method returns `Future<void>`, how should I check in FutureBuilder
is future completed or not?

Comment: Easiest way to check is to turn off your server or your wifi and try it yourself

Comment: `snapshot.connectionState`

Answer (score 1):

[AsyncSnapshot](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot-class.html) is the immutable representation of the results received from the latest interaction with the asynchrounous computation (e.g. server API call, sqlite database call, shreadpref call, etc.)

So if the latest computation resulted in an error (exception) that also this object will have in the `snapshot.error` field. SO in your case, the code should look like below:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: result,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            // Data is avialable. call snapshot.data 
          }
          else if(snapshot.hasError){     
             // Do error handling
          }
          else {
            // Still Loading. Show progressbar
          }
        });
  }
```